# How to create a responsive hamburger menu in AMP HTML

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to create an AMP HTML website (see https://www.ampproject.org)
But i can't find anywhere how you are supposed to create a responsive hamburger menu ?
Javascript is not allowed and there are no AMP Components available for it ?

Comment: Are you trying to build a multi-page website using AMP?  It's not the use-case I think AMP is designed for.  The examples I'm seeing/building are 'pages' rather than 'websites' - they are simplified views of individual articles from a non-AMP website.

Comment: @MatCarey So how can we make amp pages redundant? Do we have to make individual pages for all product to make amp details page?

Answer (score 11):

AMP now has support for menu using the [amp-sidebar](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-sidebar.html) component.

Answer (score 7):

I have accomplished this with the use of a `:target` pseudoclass.

HTML

```
<nav id="slide-in-menu">
  ...nav menu content...
</nav>
<section class="content-section">
  <a href="#slide-in-menu">Hamburger Icon</a>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#slide-in-menu {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  ... additional required styles ...
}
#slide-in-menu:target {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: This is how I would have done it as well, especially since the `:focus` pseudo-class doesn't really work on some desktop browsers due to a sort of causality paradox that seems to occur (at least in Chrome). `:target` is much more effective and it works well for carousels too, [as I've explored here.](https://dev.amdouglas.com/amphtml-examples/nojs-carousel/#div1)

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible without major hacks.

Follow along in the feature request bug: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/827

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the :focus pseudo class.  Take a look at https://fresnobee.relaymedia.com/amp/news/local/education/article61889207.html for a live example (www.washingtonpost.com also does it this way).  Or you could wait for the `<amp-sidebar>` tag to go live.

The code looks like

```
<a id="burger" tabindex="0">&#9776;</a>
<div id="burgerCancel" tabindex="0">&#9776;</div>
<div id="burgerMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/news/local/#navlink=ampnav">Local News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/sports/#navlink=ampnav">Sports</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button id="burgerMask"></button>
```

and the css

```
#burger:focus ~ #burgerMenu {
  transform: translateY(0px); /* or whatever other way you want it to appear */
}

#burgerMask {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background: #000;
z-index: 998;
border: 0;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 250ms cubic-bezier(0, .67,0,.67);
pointer-events: none; /*this is important */
}


#burger:focus ~ #burgerMask {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The live example is not working, when you click the menu item, the menu just closes and doesn't go to the url, the code in the example does the same thing. Did you ever get this code to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ivey has already mentioned `amp-sidebar`, from which everything is probably straightforward for most webdesigners, but it's worth mentioning that the AMP project also [has a tutorial](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/add_advanced/navigating) about the actual "hamburger" part.

Beware that it uses a [bagua symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua) that does not exist in every font.  Better use a picture :

```
<div role="button" on="tap:sidebar.toggle" tabindex="0" class="hamburger">
  <amp-img src="/images/logo_menu.svg" height="50" width="50">
</div>
```

In addition, before implementing it one may want to check that the hamburger menu is an appropriate solution for each particular case, since it has some downsides.  There are a number of articles online about its pros and cons and when to avoid it.