# Can I use :target

Tags: amp-html

In the [AMP Disallowed Styles](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages.html), they say:

> Pseudo-selectors, pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements are only allowed
>   in selectors that contain tag names and those tag names must not start
>   with amp-. Example OK: a:hover.

```
#thing:target {
  some style
}
```

Although the AMP test is OK, I have a doubt about such above CSS code. Can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's okay to use `:target`tag as long as it is not starting with `amp-` as stated in the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages.html#disallowed-styles) you provided. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263507/5832311) shows that the developer uses `:target` pseudoclass.

```
#slide-in-menu {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  ... additional required styles ...
}
#slide-in-menu:target {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

> *...`:target` is much more effective and it works well for carousels too*.